# Detect missing filenames in folder

Tags: powershell

Every day we receive a zipfile from a number of clients. The filename consists of the following:

```
data_clientname_timestamp.zip
```

Where "data" is always the same text, "clientname" could be anything and "timestamp" is the file creation date.

The files are always in the same directory. The clientnames are always known in advance, so I know what files should be received.

The script should do the following:

- List all files received (created) today
- If a file from one or more clients is missing, write "file from client.. missing" to a file
- I would like to list the clients in a variable, so those can easily be changed.

What I have so far:

```
$folder='C:\data'
Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -include @("*.zip") | 
    Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date )} | select name | out-file $folder\result.txt
```

But how to check the file for missing files?

Edit:
Testdata:

```
$Timestamp = (Get-Date).tostring(“yyyyMMddhhmmss”)
New-Item c:\Data -type Directory
New-Item c:\Data\Data_client1_$Timestamp.zip -type file
New-Item c:\Data\Data_client2_$Timestamp.zip -type file
New-Item c:\Data\Data_client3_$Timestamp.zip -type file
New-Item c:\Data\Data_client5_$Timestamp.zip -type file
New-Item c:\Data\Data_client6_$Timestamp.zip -type file
New-Item c:\Data\Data_client7_$Timestamp.zip -type file
exit
```

Script:

```
$folder='C:\Data'
$clients = @("client1", "client2", "client3", "client4", "client5", "client6", "client7")
$files = Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -include @("*.zip") | 
    Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date )}

$files | Select-Object Name | Out-File $folder\result.txt
$files | Where-Object { ($_.Name -replace '.+?_([^_]+).*', '$1') -notin $clients} | Out-File $folder\result2.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a list of your clients somewhere (such as in a CSV file named clients.csv) then you could loop through that list to check if a file is found for each client. For example:

```
$folder='C:\data'
$Clients = Import-CSV Clients.csv

$Files = Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -include @("*.zip") | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date )} | select name 

$Clients | ForEach-Object { 
    $Client = $_
    $ClientCheck = $Files | Where-Object {$_ -like $Client}
    If (-not $ClientCheck) { 
        Write-Warning "$Client is missing!"
    }Else{
        Write-Output $ClientCheck
    }
} | out-file $folder\result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, Im still checking this too.

Comment: I've amended my answer to use a ForEach-Object loop as you can then pipe the results out to your file.

Comment: If you want the messages about the missing files to go to a separate error file then replace that write-warning with something like `add-content -value "$Client is missing!" -path $folder\missing.txt`

Comment: This works for me. I just changed `$ClientCheck = $Files | Where-Object {$_ -like $Client}` with `$ClientCheck = $Files | Where-Object {$_ -like '*' + $Client + '*'}`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Start with defining a list of clients you would expect like:

```
$clients = @("client1", "client2")
```

Then retrieve all zip files and save it to a variable:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -include @("*.zip") | 
    Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date )}
```

Export the existing files to your result.txt:

```
$files | Select-Object Name | Out-File $folder\result.txt
```

Now you can determine each missing client using the `Where-Object` cmdlet with a regex that grabs the clientname:

```
$fileClients = $files | ForEach-Object { ($_.Name -replace '.+?_([^_]+).*', '$1') } 
Compare-Object $clients $fileClients | select -ExpandProperty InputObject | Out-File $folder\result2.txt
```

Comment: I have the folder populated with files client1 through client7 with no file for client4.

$files | Select-Object Name | Out-File $folder\result.txt
This does indeed list all files with todays creation date

$files | Where-Object { ($_.Name -replace '.+?_([^_]+).*', '$1') -notin $clients} | Out-File $folder\result2.txt
This should list "client4 missing" in result2.txt, but result2 is empty

Comment: You have to provide test data (a script that creates the files, and the script you are running it against) to reproduce it. Then we can provide an answer.